# Confirm that laptop screen broken?

Tags: hardware, display, laptop

I have a strong suspicion that the screen of my laptop Lenovo Thinkpad 450s is broken. If I plug an external monitor, I can use my laptop, and everything seems to be fine.

How can I confirm that the screen is dead? If I go to *Settings->Displays* on Ubuntu 18.04, the internal laptop screen does not show up as an option. But is there a more formal way to confirm that it is an hardware problem, resp. to diagnose where the problem is?

Thanks!

Comment: It could be the panel, but it coud also be a faulty or loose display cable or a faulty mainboard or a blown smd fuse on the mainboard. It's hard to tell what is broken without a second working display and display cable to test the components.

Comment: If you can't even see the BIOS settings on boot, it's surely a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the manual for [Hardware Maintenance from Lenovo](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t450s_hmm_en_sp40g54937_01.pdf) for your machine. Pages 52-54, 57-58, 61-62, and 81-83 have important preliminary steps,  but pages 92-95 and 98-99 show the key steps in accessing the cable from the top of the motherboard to the LCD assembly. After preparations as shown in the manual, disconnect and reconnect the ribbon cable from the display to the main board. If, after reconnecting the cable, the failure persists, it's new screen assembly time.

And, high praise to Lenovo for making these Hardware Maintenance Manuals openly available. *Every manufacturer should do this*; not all do.

Comment: great hints, thanks for this, will look at it!